# post-built event xcopy fails with exit code 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xcopy

my Xcopy fails to execute properly after I compile my project.

```
xcopy "$(SolutionDir)LuaModules\*.*" "$(TargetDir)Modules\" /S  /H /Y /C
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unneeded slash after `/S`.

Comment: removed `/`. Somehow it excecutes, but doesn't copy the files

Answer (score 0):

`$(SolutionDir)` gives the directory where the solution is in, but the project (`$ProjectDir`) gives the folder of your files. I had to use that instead